# How to create Resource Style in XAML of VisualStateManager?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visualstatemanager

Hi I have created an `ImagenButton` as below:

```
<ImageButton Source="articulos.png" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
```

And this is the code for animation:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
     <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
          <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
              <VisualState.Setters>
                  <Setter Property="Scale" Value="1"/>
              </VisualState.Setters>
          </VisualState>
          <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
              <VisualState.Setters>
                  <Setter Property="Scale" Value="0.8"/>
              </VisualState.Setters>
           </VisualState>
       </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

but I want create many buttons with same style, I do not want code repetition.

This is the complete code:

```
<ImageButton Source="articulos.png" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked">               
     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
             <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                 <VisualState.Setters>
                     <Setter Property="Scale" Value="1"/>
                 </VisualState.Setters>
             </VisualState>
             <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                 <VisualState.Setters>
                     <Setter Property="Scale" Value="0.8"/>
                 </VisualState.Setters>
              </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
 </ImageButton>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define styles in your page, and then apply them to your Controls:

```
<StackLayout.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ImageButton">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale" Value="1"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale" Value="0.8"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</StackLayout.Resources
```

Check the official documentation, it has there [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager)